# Al hacerle un print a un archivo binario me sale esto:<__main__.Usuario object at 0x0000018A730DC2B0>

Tags: python

Aun estoy estudiando Python, pero como ejercicio me decidí a hacer una aplicación donde te puedas registrar o iniciar sesión, y que guarde los datos de los usuarios que se registran en un archivo externo en binario, para luego usarlo para comprobar el inicio de sesión. El problema es que cuando le hago el print a la variable que cargo el archivo binario me sale esto:

```
[<__main__.Usuario object at 0x0000018A730DC2B0>, <__main__.Usuario object at 0x0000018A730DC280>, <__main__.Usuario object at 0x0000018A730DC640>, <__main__.Usuario object at 0x0000018A730DC6D0>, <__main__.Usuario object at 0x0000018A730DC700>, <__main__.Usuario object at 0x0000018A730DC730>]
```

Ya se que sale así porque lo que estoy guardando es los datos que le paso a la clase, pero no se como solucionarlo manteniendo la clase.
El codigo tiene 250 líneas así que lo mando simplificado:

```
#Con esto guardo los datos personales

import pickel
class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, correo, Contra):
        self.correo = correo
        self.Contra = Contra


    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format( self.correo, self.Contra)

class ListaUsuarios:

    personas = []

    def __init__(self):

        ListaDeUsuarios=open("DatosClientes","ab+")
        ListaDeUsuarios.seek(0)

        try:
            self.personas=pickle.load(ListaDeUsuarios)
            print("Se cargaron {} personas del fichero externo".format(len(self.personas)))
        except:
            print("El fichero esta vacio")
        finally:
            ListaDeUsuarios.close()
            del(ListaDeUsuarios)

    def agregarPersonas(self,p):
        self.personas.append(p)
        self.guardarPersonasEnFicheroExterno()

    def guardarPersonasEnFicheroExterno(self):
        ListaDeUsuarios=open("DatosClientes", "wb")
        pickle.dump(self.personas, ListaDeUsuarios)
        ListaDeUsuarios.close()
        del(ListaDeUsuarios)

#Voy a escribirlos asi ya como palabras para ahorrar y que se vea mejor, pero en mi aplicación al tener interfaz gráfica hago un .get del correo y de la contraseña.

DatosPersonales=Usuario("email", "asdf")
miLista=ListaUsuarios()
miLista.agregarPersonas(DatosPersonales)


#Y esto es lo que he hecho para que me salga lo de main.

File=open("DatosClientes","rb")
FileText=pickle.load(File)
print(FileText)
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: También debes implementar el dunder método `__repr__` en el cual colocarias lo mismo que esta en `__str__`

Comment: Muchas gracias, no conocía el método repr, pero una duda, sabes como pasar el output del repr a un array? Gracias

Comment: `self.datos.append([self.correo, self.Contra]); return f"{self.correo}, {self.Contra}"` primero crea el atributo `self.datos=[]`. El `__repr__` es un método al igual que cualquier otro que quieras implementar, la diferencia es que este tiene que retornar un string y es llamado utilizado por funciones más internas de python